# how to copy _PublishedWebsites Files?

Tags: batch-file, tfs, msbuild

In Fact, I use Visual Studio 2013, and I want to copy the _PublishedWebsites Files using a batch file after deployment of my build , so this is an image to my **Build Definitions**:

[image]

I'm using in the batch file, this command:

```
xcopy /s ...\_PublishedWebsites\subfolders ...\main\Service >> ...\output.txt
```

To be sure that the copy works well, I wrote the result of copying operation in output.txt, so the result is:

```
0 File(s) copied
```

I noticed that the copy operation was done before than the _Publishedfiles files are created.

Do you know how can I copy the _Publishedfiles files after their complilation ?

In addition, I don't have the rights for changing in .xaml files :(

Comment: Do you have access to the build server? Can you check the location of your script and the PublishedWebsites directory?

Comment: yes I have and I can check the location of my script

Answer (score 0):

Use publish profile and type file system which will copy _PublishedWebsites to sharelocation/location

for publish profile see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you but your answer is not that I want ... –

Answer (score 0):

If you know _PublishedWebSites directory on build machine you can copy files to path you want . You can do something like this, i used this task for same issue.

```
<ItemGroup >
 <MyProjectSource Include="$(OutputRoot)/MySource/**/*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="AfterCopy" AfterTargets="WebPublish">
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyProjectSource)" 
   OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" DestinationFolder="$(PublishFolder)/%    (RecursiveDir)"/>
```

> OutputRoot = your _PublishedWebsites  path
>
> MySource = your project
>
> PublishFolder = your destination folder

You can do like this in your csproj file or if you use tfs build definition you  can add a copy file task step to defintion and just fill paramaters.